# Xamarin android crashing after upgrading to android 10

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I tried to update app to android 10 api level 30, app crashing with below error.

```
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in com.logesh.admin:layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in com.logesh.admin:layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

advance thanks

Comment: Did you still use the package android.support.v7 in your project ? Here is a similar thread that maybe can help you https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126072/binary-xml-file-line-14-error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-fitwindowslinearlayout

Comment: tried that one, not working

Comment: So it works fine on Android 9 and before ?

Comment: yes it working in production fine:)

Comment: Could you post the relevant code that cause the issue ?